# MVC3 - merging htmlAttributes set in View with ones set in Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using [Disable autocomplete on html helper textbox in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274407/disable-autocomplete-on-html-helper-textbox-in-mvc) to add autocomplete to "off" on text boxes:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return html.TextBoxFor(expression, new { autocomplete = "off" });
    }
```

This is fine if there are no htmlAttributes on the view.  Some of the textfields also have an extra CSS class added to them:

```
    @Html.NoAutoCompleteTextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "ignore" })
```

Rather than specifically create another helper for this, is there a way to merge the sets of htmlAttributes?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RouteValueDictionary.

```
var attrs = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
attrs ["autocomplete"] = "off";
return html.TextBoxFor(expression, attrs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of cause. When passing an object into the helper, you can use reflection to read all the properties (which correspond to the html attributes you want to set) and pass the combined attributes as Dictionary to the helper:

```
Dictionary<string, object> attrs = new Dictionary<string, object>();

if (htmlAttributes != null)
{
    foreach (var prop in htmlAttributes.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        attrs[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(htmlAttributes, null);
    }
}

// now add your own attribute(s):
htmlAttributes["autocomplete"] = "off";

return html.TextBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
```